# What type of protectionist measure is this?

Tags: international-trade

I am currently studying an economics case study on protectionist measures but came across a measure which I have not heard off before, one which research has not shed any light on. The case study gives examples of protectionist measures from a range of countries, the one I am confused about reads:

> Fuel for official cars in Argentina can only be bought from state-owned oil companies

The protectionist measures such as tariffs and quotas do not seem to apply here. Further research gives [this](http://www.sanandres.esc.edu.ar/secondary/economics%20packs/international_economics/page_18.htm) list of protectionist measures, but this doesn't appear to fit in one of those categories either.

Several Google searches have turned up no results either.

**My Question:** What type of protectionist measure is the example above?

Comment: Within the WTO framework, this would fall under the [government procurement agreement](https://www.wto.org/english/docs_e/legal_e/rev-gpr-94_01_e.htm#articleVIII), as it is a restriction on who the government can buy from that limits opportunities for foreign firms.

Comment: @Dan thanks for the comment, would you like to leave it as an answer so it can be upvoted and accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the WTO framework, this would fall under the [government procurement agreement](https://www.wto.org/english/docs_e/legal_e/rev-gpr-94_01_e.htm), as it is a restriction on who the government can buy from that limits opportunities for foreign firms.